Including failure reasons in Jenkins email notification
I want to have failed tests/builds information directly in the email from Jenkins, rather than having to follow a link and scroll through console log to find the problem.
I've spent all day trying different variants, including trying to open and parse the log file, or sending the whole thing, and now using JELLY_SCRIPT, but in every case, the problem I have is that the failure task is apparently invoked before the failure reason is actually logged, so the information received includes everything (including the fact the email is being sent) except the reason. This seems such a basic use case, I suppose the solution must be obvious, but I still haven't found what I'm looking for.
Here's my test pipeline code:
pipeline {
    agent { label '' }
    environment {
        AccessToken = credentials('xxx')
        CredentialsIdEsd = "xxx"
    }
  
    stages {
        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                script {
                    error 'This is a deliberate failure'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            script{
                emailext subject: "Failed" + " for ${JOB_NAME} JOB#${BUILD_NUMBER}",
                         body:  '${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}',
                         from: "Jenkins Build <no-reply@example.com>",
                         to: "mail@example.com"
            }
        }
    }
}


Using error to test catching errors was a bad idea, apparently.
It seems to be the equivalent of "exit 1", which kills the pipeline (or something, I've given up trying to understand).
Putting something else in that doesn't work (like a build error or failing unit test), does get caught and shows up in the email.
(Wish we hadn't dumped TeamCity for Jenkins...)
